# Fulltext Postgres

Tags: postgresql, indexing, full-text-search, tsvector

I created an index for full text search in postgresql.

```
CREATE INDEX pesquisa_idx 
ON chamado 
USING 
gin(to_tsvector('portuguese', coalesce(titulo,'') || coalesce(descricao,'')));
```

When I run this query:

```
SELECT * FROM chamado WHERE to_tsvector('portuguese', titulo) @@ 'ura'
```

It returned to me some rows.

But when my argument is in all uppercase, no rows are returned. For example:

```
SELECT * FROM chamado WHERE to_tsvector('portuguese', titulo) @@ 'URA'
```

When the argument is 'ura' I get a few lines; when the argument is 'URA' I do not get any rows.

Why does this happen?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You get no matches in the second case since to_tsvector() lowercases all lexemes. Use to_tsquery() to build the query, it will take care of the case issues as well:

```
SELECT * FROM chamado WHERE to_tsvector('portuguese', titulo) @@ to_tsquery('portuguese', 'URA')
```